# CodeIgniter BMI calculator not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been using Codeigniter for an assignment in university and I cannot seem to get this to work, any feedback and fixes are greatly appreciated. The errors returned are:

- Undefined index: submit
- Undefined variable: weight
- Undefined variable: height
- Division by zero

This is the code that doesnt work, it is a file in the views folder:

```
<div id="container">
<h1>BMI and Blood Pressure Calculator</h1>

<div id="body">
    <p>This webpage allows users to calculate their BMI and Blood Pressure by entering in their values into the boxes</p>
    </br>           
    <p>Please enter in your details below</p>

<form>
     <br />
     <br />Patient Information
     <br />Height <input type="text" name="height" size="12" maxlength="20">
     <br />Weight <input type="text" name="weight" size="12" maxlength="20">
     <br />
     <br /><input type="reset" value="Clear Form">
     <br /><input type="submit" value="Submit Information">
</form>
</div>

<?php

        $this->input->post('height');
        $this->input->post('weight');

          if ($_GET['submit']) {
          $height = $_GET['height'];
          $weight = $_GET['weight'];
        }
          function bmi($height,$weight) {
            $bmi = $weight/($height*$height);
            return $bmi;
        }

            $bmi = bmi($weight,$height);

              if ($bmi <= 15) {
                $output = "Very severely underweight";

              } else if ($bmi > 15 AND $bmi<=16 ) {
                $output = "Severely underweight";

              } else if ($bmi > 16 AND $bmi<=18.5) {
                $output = "Underweight";

              } else if ($bmi > 18.5 AND $bmi<=25) {
                $output = "Normal";

              } else if ($bmi > 25 AND $bmi<=30) {
                $output = "Overweight";

              } else if ($bmi > 30 AND $bmi<=35) {
                $output = "Obesity class 1";

              } else if ($bmi > 35 AND $num<=40) {
                $output = "Obesity class 2";

              } else if ($bmi > 60) {
                $output = "Obesity class 3";

              echo "Your BMI is " . $bmi . " and you are : ";
              echo "$output";

              }
        ?>
```

Comment: You are trying to post and get data from where? How do you send this data? Attach also the file that you are handling the inputs

Comment: Im inputting data via a form and trying to use that data to calculate the inputted data

Comment: Yes but how do you send your data? Also your form is not included in your file. Attach also the html please

Comment: it's better to use `isset` or `!empty` when checking for GET/POST/REQUEST variables.

Comment: All i really need is a way to declare the variables and fix the division problem, thank you for your replies

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your view page gets to access `$this->input` directly unless you pass it from the controller to the view. The ideal way to do this would be

on submit of the form receive the values in the controller [ you will need to post to `localhost/project_folder/Calc` ]

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calc extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['height'] = $this->input->post('height', true);
        $data['weight'] = $this->input->post('weight', true);
        $this->load->view('page_which_contains_your_logic',$data);
    }
}
```

Then on the page you can do the following

```
echo $height." ".$weight;
```

You should have a better look at the codeigniter documentation to see how data flows between the model, view and controllers.